# Events for HighCharts - MouseOver/MouseOut

Tags: highcharts, mouseover, mouseleave

I'm using the HighCharts-Stock, and need to detect when mouse hovers over one of the points in the chart.
Here's my code:

```
 window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
 plotOptions: {
            area: {
                point: {
                    events: {
                        mouseOver: function () {
                            alert('over');
                        },
                        mouseOut: function () {
                            alert('out');
                        },
                        select: function () {
                            alert('select');
                        },
                        unselect: function () {
                            alert('unselect');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }, .....}
```

but non of these events fires!
How can I enable them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "area" was replaced with "line", it will work!
because this indicates the type of chart I'm using.

Comment: You can use `series` to match all series.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add min value with "earlier" date, and then set tickInverval.